# Mudar dinamicamente a opacidade de uma browser window de uma aplicação em electron

Tags: javascript, css, electron

É possível mudar a opacidade dinamicamente em tempo de execução de uma browser window do electron? Se sim, como isso pode ser feito? Eu desejo ter um slider que controla a opacidade enquanto a aplicação está rodando.